# modifying curl command to ansible uri module

Tags: curl, ansible

I've been trying to execute a curl command from the Ansible URI module, but it's not working. can anyone help me understand the mistake I'm doing??

the CURL command is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "X-Vuls-OS-Family: `lsb_release -si | awk '{print tolower($1)}'`" -H "X-Vuls-OS-Release: `lsb_release -sr | awk '{print $1}'`" -H "X-Vuls-Kernel-Release: `uname -r`" -H "X-Vuls-Server-Name: `hostname`" --data-binary "$(dpkg-query -W -f="\${binary:Package},\${db:Status-Abbrev},\${Version},\${Source},\${source:Version}\n")" https://abc.xyz.co/vuls > /path/to/report.json**
```

on comma

The playbook I'm using right now is:

```
- hosts: localhost
  ignore_errors: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Run Vuls Scans
      uri:
        method: POST
        url: https://abc.xyz.co/vuls
        headers:
          Content-Type: text/plain
          X-Vuls-OS-Family: lsb_release -si | awk '{print tolower($1)}'
          X-Vuls-OS-Release: lsb_release -sr | awk '{print $1}'
          X-Vuls-Kernel-Release: uname -r
          X-Vuls-Server-Name: hostname
        creates: /home/aman/vuls-report.json
```

I know this playbook is still not complete because I'm unable to manage some part of command in playbook (`**--data-binary "$(dpkg-query -W -f="\${binary:Package},\${db:Status-Abbrev},\${Version},\${Source},\${source:Version}\n")"**`). Apology for that but i don't know how to manage it in playbook. Can anyone help me in this problem.
Thank you

PS: I've seen some existing issues on this ansible URI module and curl method on StackOverflow, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run arbitrary Shell commands inside an Ansible module. However, as you are gathering [facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) about your host, you can leverage these. Try something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  ignore_errors: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Run Vuls Scans
      uri:
        method: POST
        url: https://abc.xyz.co/vuls
        headers:
          Content-Type: text/plain
          X-Vuls-OS-Family: "{{ ansible_distribution }}"
          X-Vuls-OS-Release: "{{ ansible_distribution_version}}"
          X-Vuls-Kernel-Release: "{{ ansible_kernel }}"
          X-Vuls-Server-Name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        creates: /home/aman/vuls-report.json
```

For more complex information, like your `dpkg` query, you could do something like

```
- name: dpkg query
  shell: "dpkg-query -W -f='\${binary:Package},\${db:Status-Abbrev},\${Version},\${Source},\${source:Version}\n'"
  register: query_results

- name: check variable content
  debug:
    var: query_results
```

Disclaimer: This is **untested**, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Note that the use of `creates` without `dest` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: As I said, it's not a copy-paste solution since it is (and will remain) untested by me. However, patterns like using Jinja2 templating inside modules should point you to the right documentation pages. You can also update your question to display your latest progress and elaborate the error(s) you are facing.